# Turning features on/off at compile time: #if vs. wrapper vs. empty implementation

Tags: c, design-patterns, embedded

I have a C codebase for some embedded project that can be configured to run on a number of different PCBs with different hardware peripheral devices.

Configuration files dictate which of these devices are enabled or disabled, and I could use something like

```
#if FEATURE
do_something()
#endif
```

in order to enable it.

I can also use these variables in the build scripts to turn compilation of files on/off conditionally.

Now in my case calls that interact with these devices are all over the code. But, I don't want the implementation of these calls to be compiled into the binary, as it increases the size and allocates things like static variables which eat up my precious RAM (including some large buffers for storing messages that go up a network stack, for instance).

So I could use these `#if` statements all over the code to prevent compilation errors when I turn off compilation of the relevant .c files (but include the interface .h files). But even then, it becomes quite an "ifdef hell" which in my opinion makes the code badly readable.

So I've been trying to come up with alternatives. The options I have thought of so far:

1. use wrapper functions that contain the #ifdef inside, so the main code does not suffer from this unreadability:

```
void do_something() {
#if FEATURE
    do_something_inner();
#endif
}
```

2. add a different "dummy" .c file with an empty implementation for each interface I want to turn off and compile that .c file instead of the real implementation whenever my feature is turned off (or vice versa):

```
/// something_dummy.c
void do_something(){}

/// something_real.c
void do_something(){
    implementation goes here
}
```

What do you think is the best option and why? Or is there an option I haven't thought of?

(If it matters, I'm using Zephyr RTOS and generate the configuration using KConfig, which can be passed into both CMake and a C file containing the relevant #defines).

Comment: Why `#if` over `#ifdef`? Is some special value required?

Comment: @Lundin usually it is defined as either true or false, and `#ifdef false` evaluates to true

Answer (score 0):

This might be an option:

- Define a function template/format which all these functions have to follow.
- For each category of functions, create a function pointer jump table based on pre-processor conditions.
- This means that only functions that are present in the jump table will be used by the code and others will/may get discarded during linking.
- Dimention the jump table for all supported cases but set unused ones to null as part of the pre-processor selection.

This can be as simple or as advanced as you chose to make it. I made a very flexible example below, which allows you to leave out or include things in pretty much any way you want.

---

Given a list of corresponding function groups of some type:

```
void init_something      (void) { puts(__func__); }
void init_something_else (void) { puts(__func__); }
void init_stuff          (void) { puts(__func__); }
void do_something        (void) { puts(__func__); }
void do_something_else   (void) { puts(__func__); }
void do_stuff            (void) { puts(__func__); }
```

Make a corresponding enum:

```
typedef enum
{
  something,
  something_else,
  stuff,

  features_n  // number of maximum features
} all_possible_features_t;
```

Define function templates:

```
typedef void init_function (void);
typedef void do_stuff_function (void);
```

Create a struct per group of related functions:

```
typedef struct
{
  init_function* const      init_func;
  do_stuff_function* const  do_func;
} supported_features_t;
```

Next the only place in where the various pre-processor goo goes, centralized in one place, when you define the jump table and leave unused items as null:

```
static const supported_features_t supported_features [features_n] =
{
  #if HELL && HIGH_WATER
    [something]      = { .init_func = init_something,      .do_func = do_something },
    [something_else] = { .init_func = init_something_else, .do_func = do_something_else },
  #elif defined(NULL)
    [something]      = { .init_func = init_something,      .do_func = do_something },
    [something_else] = { .init_func = init_something_else, .do_func = do_something_else },
    [stuff]          = { .init_func = init_stuff,          .do_func = do_stuff },
  #elif 1+1 == 3
    /* ... */
  #endif
};
```

Example of usage:

```
int main (void)
{
  /* init everything supported */
  for(size_t i=0; i<features_n; i++)
  {
    if(supported_features[i].init_func != NULL)
    {
      supported_features[i].init_func();
    }
  }

  /* do stuff with everything supported */
  for(size_t i=0; i<features_n; i++)
  {
    if(supported_features[i].do_func != NULL)
    {
      supported_features[i].do_func();
    }
  }  
}
```

Complete example code: https://godbolt.org/z/Ga6d9P8PM

Comment: Almost like using variadic templates in C++ which all follow the same interface.

Unfortunately, in my case all these "features" do not implement one interface and some calls get called all over the code only for one feature, and trying to force all of them under one interface would not really make sense here.

Comment: @BorisMulder You could probably "type pun" between different function pointer types at some extent, using unions and similar. Anyway, this would be why we start with the program design _before_ writing the program, instead of the other way around :)

Comment: Not really in my case, since some of the features include a bluetooth stack which sends small info data at at a certain interval, and a USB stack which can send a large stream only when the user requests it (using some handshakes/protocol). They just do completely different things.

Comment: @BorisMulder Can't you place abstraction layers on top of it all then and otherwise let them go about their business independently? Are you using RTOS or is it bare metal? With RTOS the most obvious abstraction layer would be different processes.

Comment: in the end that would bottle down to the wrappers I proposed, which have the additional advantage of allowing to send the info data over another channel instead of bluetooth for example with minimal code changes.

Answer (score 0):

The first code block in @Lundin's answer gave me an idea.

Basically the idea is to add dummy `static` functions in the header file for each bit of code that can be disabled, in the case where you want to disable the functionality. You then don't need to remove calls to those functions - if you compile with optimisation enabled, the calls will be removed by the compiler, since it knows the function is static and does nothing. Then you just don't compile and link the file you want to "disable".

So something like:

main.c

```c
#include "something.h"

int main(void)
{
  do_something(1);
  do_something_2(2, 3);

  return 0;
}
```

something.c

```c
void do_something(int a)
{
  // Real code goes here
}

int do_something_2(int b, int c)
{
  return b + c;
}
```

something.h

```c
#ifndef SOMETHING_H
#define SOMETHING_H

#ifdef USE_SOMETHING

void do_something(int a);
int do_something_2(int b, int c);

#else

static void do_something(int a){}
static int do_something_2(int b, int c){return 0;}

#endif

#endif
```

Makefile:

```makefile
all: something nothing

CFLAGS = -Wall -O3

something: main.c something.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DUSE_SOMETHING $^ -o $@

nothing: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean:; rm -f nothing something
```

Result:

```
$ nm something | grep something
0000000000001160 T do_something
0000000000001170 T do_something_2
$ nm nothing | grep something
$
```

The benefits are:

1. You don't need to modify any of the callers.
2. You don't need to modify the code that you are basically removing (e.g. in something.c).
3. You just modify the header file for each file that can be "disabled".
4. You don't need to make a new `.c` file to stub out the removed functions. It all happens in the `.h` file.
5. Not only does it completely remove the disabled functions from the binary, it also removes all the calls to them. (Rather than say calling actual non-static dummy functions, where the call would still happen.)

Comment: You could have done also `#define do_something(a) /* none */`and `#define do_something_2(b,c) (0)` in the disabled feature branch, and surround the .c impl of the functions also with its feature test  ... Your something.c file does not use the same declaration of the functions, since you did most likely not include the something.h file there. That's why you don't have a error reported. If you change signature in .h or .c they would not match, and the calls would fail.

Comment: @kesselhaus Adding `#include "something.h"` to `something.c` does not change the behaviour. Remember, `something.c` does not even get built if we're not using it. Using `#define` might also be a way to do it, but I don't prefer it.

Comment: While we don't need a .c file and instead stub them in the .h file, one disadvantage I see here is that the function definition needs to be declared twice. If you ever want to change the signature (e.g. to add a parameter), you will need to change it at two places (Shotgun Surgery). Though you might have the same issue with the two different .c files.

Comment: @BorisMulder That's true. On the other hand, it checks that you are using the correct number and type of parameters even for code that is stubbed out in your build, which you would lose if you just `#define`d the function calls into oblivion.